# capture alphanumeric string using regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file that contain any of the following strings

```
"155"
>555.123.4567
>555-123-4567
>(555).123.4567
>(555)123-4567
>(555)-123-4567
```

I would like to capture the strings except the 1st with the output like below using regex

```
555.123.4567
555-123-4567
(555).123.4567
(555)123-4567
(555)-123-4567
```

So far I am only able to come up with the regex below but it work only to the last three strings

```
/(\([\d]+\).\-?(-|)[\d]+.-?[\d]+)/g
```

Comment: which dot i will escape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with optional delimiters to match your inputs:

```
/[(]?\d{3}[)]?[.-]?\d{3}[.-]?\d{4}\b/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zY1yY7/1)

Comment: I modified the code a bit to appear like below it worked.
([(]?\d{3}[)]?[.-]?\d{3}[.-]?\d{4})

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to search for

1. Three digits in parentheses, or just three digits
2. A dot or a hyphen, or nothing
3. Three more digits
4. At least one dot or hyphen
5. Four more digits

This regex is a transliteration of that. Note that it's always sensible to add the `/x` modifier with complex patterns so that you can add insignificant spaces and newlines to make your program more readable

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

while ( <DATA> ) {
    next unless / (
        (?: \( \d{3} \) | \d{3} )
        ([.-]|)
        \d{3}
        [.-]
        \d{4}
    ) /x;

    say $1;

}


__DATA__
"155"
>555.123.4567
>555-123-4567
>(555).123.4567
>(555)123-4567
>(555)-123-4567
```

#### output

```
555.123.4567
555-123-4567
(555).123.4567
(555)123-4567
(555)-123-4567
```

But that's very specific, and it looks like you're verifying manually-input phone numbers. I'm not sure you wouldn't be better off with this

1. Some digits and parentheses
2. A dot or a hyphen
3. More digits, dots, or hyphens

which looks like this

```
/ ( [()\d]+ [.-] [\d.-]+  ) /x
```